# How to refresh a table in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this in another page which I loading using jquery load.What I want is table to refresh the data after each change as I am searching the data.The table should refresh and load again with the latest search results.Please help me regarding this.
table.jsp

```
<div id="displayTabl" >
<table border="1" id="tableShow" bordercolor="#BDBBBC" cellpadding="12">
  <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#996533" width="250">Record Id</th>
      <th bgcolor="#996533" width="250">Name</th>
      <th bgcolor="#996533" width="125">Mobile</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Here is my snippet of the loading table javascript code.

```
    var txt = "";
    //    $("#tableShow").table("refresh");
    var dataJ = JSON.parse(response);
    $.each(dataJ, function(i, val) {
        txt += "<tr><td>" + val.id + "</td><td>" + val.name_s + "</td><td>" + val.mobile_s + "</td></tr>";
    });
    if(txt != "") {
        $("#tableShow").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
    }
    console.log(dataJ);
```

Comment: Why don't your try this **[plugin](https://www.datatables.net/)**

Comment: Sorry cannot use any plugins other than standard jquery and jquery mobile plugins.

Comment: what is happening with your current `snippet`?

Comment: for every refresh you can empty table column with  $("#tableShow").html(''); and insert tr,td tags with
append() again

Comment: Works!! I had to recreate the row each time dynamically.